# Content data not showing for sap.m.MessageView inside Dialog popup after DELETE request completed

Tags: javascript, sapui5, crud

In my `blHandleDelButtonPressed()` function I am doing a DELETE entry request on single/multiple selected table row(s). After the request is DONE (after `success` / `error`) I would like to display a Message View inside Dialog ( `sap.m.MessageView` exactly like this one here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MessageView/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageViewInsideDialog ).

The problem is when the request is DONE, the Message View pops up, but it contains no data ↓↓↓
[image: Problem - Message View contains no content data]

Here's the sample code:

```
displayMsgDialog: function(oDialog) {
    oDialog.open();
},
blHandleDelButtonPressed: function(oEvent) { 
    var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("bookingsList");
    var oSelectedItems = oTable.getSelectedItems();
    var aBookingRemovals = [];

    oTable.setBusy(true);

    oSelectedItems.forEach(function(selectedItem) {
        var oBooking = selectedItem.getBindingContext();
        var sPath =  oBooking.getPath(),
            sBookId = oBooking.getProperty("bookid"),
            sPassName = oBooking.getProperty("PASSNAME"),
            sCustomId = oBooking.getProperty("CUSTOMID");

        oModel.remove(sPath, {
            success: function(oData, response) {
                aBookingRemovals.push({
                    type: "Success",
                    title: "Booking " + sBookId + " successfully removed",
                    subtitle: "Book ID: " + sBookId + " | Passager: " + sPassName + " | ID: " + sCustomId
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                aBookingRemovals.push({
                    type: "Error",
                    title: "Booking " + selectedItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("bookid") + " wasn't removed",
                    subtitle: "Book ID: " + sBookId + " | Passager: " + sPassName + " | ID: " + sCustomId
                });
            }
        }); 
    });

    oTable.setBusy(false); 

    var oBookingRemovalsTpl = new sap.m.MessageItem({
        type: "{type}",
        title: "{title}",
        subtitle: "{subtitle}"
    });

    var oModelBookingRemovals = new JSONModel();
    oModelBookingRemovals.setData(aBookingRemovals);

    this.oBookingRemovalsView = new sap.m.MessageView({
        showDetailsPageHeader: false,
        items: {
            path: "/",
            template: oBookingRemovalsTpl
        }
    });

    this.oBookingRemovalsView.setModel(oModelBookingRemovals, "BookingRemovals");

    this.oBookingRemovalsDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
        resizable: true,
        content: this.oBookingRemovalsView,
        state: 'Information',
        beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
            press: function () {
                this.getParent().close();
                oTable.removeSelections();
                aBookingRemovals = []; 
            },
            text: "Close"
        }),
        customHeader: new sap.m.Bar({
            contentMiddle: [
                new sap.m.Text({ text: "We tried to remove selected bookings"})
            ]
        }),
        contentHeight: "300px",
        contentWidth: "500px",
        verticalScrolling: false
    });

    // Displaying the final Message View inside Dialog
    this.displayMsgDialog(this.oBookingRemovalsDialog);
}
```

The browser's console doesn't show any errors / warnings.

**Strange thing:**

After I selected 3 random rows and executed the `blHandleDelButtonPressed()` function, I called `detail.oBookingRemovalsView.getModel("BookingRemovals").getData()` in Chrome's console, that gave me this ↓↓↓ (As you can see, data from selected rows were inserted into the `BookingRemovals` model and binded to `window.detail.oBookingRemovalsView`)

```
> detail.oBookingRemovalsView.getModel("BookingRemovals").getData()

   (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
      1: {type: "Error", title: "Booking 00000001 wasn't removed", subtitle: "Book ID: 00000001 | Passager: Benjamin Waldmann | ID: 00004113"}
      2: {type: "Error", title: "Booking 00000002 wasn't removed", subtitle: "Book ID: 00000002 | Passager: Adam Gutenberg | ID: 00002720"}
      3: {type: "Error", title: "Booking 00000005 wasn't removed", subtitle: "Book ID: 00000005 | Passager: Juan Martin | ID: 00003740"}
      length: 5
      __proto__: Array(0)
```

However when I called `detail.oBookingRemovalsView.getItems()`, I got an empty array ↓↓↓

```
> detail.oBookingRemovalsView.getItems()

   []
      length: 0
      __proto__: Array(0)
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Your code is async. `success` and `error` are called **AFTER** `this.displayMsgDialog(this.oBookingRemovalsDialog);` because they are callbacks.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but I would recommend not creating a new model everytime you do a new delete operation – in my experience this creates problems with the bindings. Better split the logic here.

Comment: @Marc @pguddi I wonder is there a `done` / `complete` parameter like in regular vanilla JS? `async: false` doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Build your own Promise using vanilla js. You can `resolve` it in the `success` method and `reject` it in the `error` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to build a promise for each selected element. If all promises are resolved, call a `then` function which now has access to the resolved objects from the `success` and the `error` function.

```
blHandleDelButtonPressed: function(oEvent) { 
    var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("bookingsList");
    var aSelectedItems = oTable.getSelectedItems();
    // var aBookingRemovals = [];

    oTable.setBusy(true);

    // map applies a function to every element of an array 
    // and stores the returned value in a new array
    var aPromises = aSelectedItems.map(function(selectedItem) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var oBooking = selectedItem.getBindingContext();
            var sPath =  oBooking.getPath(),
                sBookId = oBooking.getProperty("bookid"),
                sPassName = oBooking.getProperty("PASSNAME"),
                sCustomId = oBooking.getProperty("CUSTOMID");

            oModel.remove(sPath, {
                success: function(oData, response) {
                    // pass the following object to the THEN function
                    resolve({
                        type: "Success",
                        title: "Booking " + sBookId + " successfully removed",
                        subtitle: "Book ID: " + sBookId + " | Passager: " + sPassName + " | ID: " + sCustomId
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    // pass the following object to the THEN function
                    // when using Promise.all you don't want to use reject
                    // otherwise the resolved promises will get lost
                    resolve({
                        type: "Error",
                        title: "Booking " + selectedItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("bookid") + " wasn't removed",
                        subtitle: "Book ID: " + sBookId + " | Passager: " + sPassName + " | ID: " + sCustomId
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
    });

    Promise.all(aPromises).then(function(aResolvedValues) {
        // aResolvedValues contains all values that have been resolved
        // it should look exactly the same as aBookingRemovals
        // if we got here, all calls have been finished. this is a much better place to call 
        oTable.setBusy(false); 

        // add the rest of the code here
    });
```

Read more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Read more about [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Read more about [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks. Also I could have simply used $AJAX with `complete` callback which is executed after `success` and `error`

Comment: Yes, but personally I am not a fan of jQuery (yet another dependency)